# count the number of questions in examdesign

Tags: counters, exam, examdesign

I write somes exams using the `examdesign` class and others using the `exam` class. Each has its benefits.

One feature about `exam` that I really like is the macro `\numquestions` which counts the numbers of questions (defined by `\question`) in the exam. I wish this feature existed for `examdesign`. So I am trying to add it myself. However, I am new to counters.

In `examdesign` questions are defined by an environment:

```
\begin{question}
\end{question}
```

and from my initial reading of counters it should be possible to define a counter that simply counts the number of times this environment is used.

Does one need redefine an environment so that it can be counted? Or can one define a counter that follows a pre-existing environment?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SectionFont{\large\bfseries\ttfamily}
\ContinuousNumbering
\Fullpages
\NoKey
\NumberOfVersions{1}

\let\namedata\relax

\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}
This exam is worth all the marbles. It contains \thequestion\ questions.
\end{examtop}

\begin{multiplechoice}[]
\begin{question}
  True?
    \choice[!]{True.}
    \choice{False.}
    \choice{Maybe.}
    \choice{Dunno.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{shortanswer}[]
\begin{question}
What is love?
\begin{answer}
Baby don't hurt me. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}


\begin{examclosing}
This exam contained \thequestion\ questions. 
\end{examclosing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems I cannot compile the examdesign class with texlive 2017, but from its source code, it has a counter `question` that counts the questions. You should be able to access the value with `\thequestion`. In case you need this number before the last question, the `totcount` can help with that.

Comment: `\thequestion` will just print "1". Not sure what it is counting - but it is not counting the total number of questions.

Comment: Where did you put it the code? (please use @ in front of my name to ping me)

Comment: @samcarter see the updated MWE. `\thequestion` is put at the beginning and the end of the exam but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the total number of questions is enough, you could simply define a new counter and use the `etoolbox` package to increase this counter for every question.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SectionFont{\large\bfseries\ttfamily}
\ContinuousNumbering
\Fullpages
\NoKey
\NumberOfVersions{1}

\let\namedata\relax

\newcounter{qcount}
\setcounter{qcount}{0}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\addtocounter{qcount}{1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}
This exam is worth all the marbles. It contains \theqcount\ questions.
\end{examtop}

\begin{multiplechoice}[]
\begin{question}
  True?
    \choice[!]{True.}
    \choice{False.}
    \choice{Maybe.}
    \choice{Dunno.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{shortanswer}[]
\begin{question}
What is love?
\begin{answer}
Baby don't hurt me. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}


\begin{examclosing}
This exam contained \theqcount\ questions. 
\end{examclosing}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Short follow-up: can the counter distinguish between question environments? Say, count MC questions and count short-answer questions.

Comment: @invictus Yes, if you want this don't increment the counter for the question environment, but for `multiplechoice`

Comment: the trouble is I want to count both MC and short answer questions. I'll open a new question.