# count the number of question types in examdesign

Tags: counters, exam, examdesign

In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393196/count-the-number-of-questions-in-examdesign/393291?noredirect=1#comment977444_393291) I asked how to count the total number of questions in an exam. Now I am curious how to count the number of questions types - e.g. multiple choice and short answer.

I borrowed from @samcarter's nice solution and defined unique counters for multiple choice, short answer and all questions using `etoolbox`. However, they do not work as planned. There are 5 total questions. The total question counter (`thenumquestions`) is correct, and so is the short answer question counter (`thesa`), but the multiple choice question counter (`\themc`) is counting all questions.

The trouble is that all questions are defined by `\begin{question}`, and I am trying to count those instances separately within each question type (`\begin{multiplechoice}` and `\begin{shortanswer}`).

I also tried to borrow from this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139841/how-to-count-the-number-of-questions-separately-for-different-parts-in-exam-clas) to unique counting in the `exam` class by defining different environments for different questions, but it throws an error.

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SectionFont{\large\bfseries\ttfamily}
\ContinuousNumbering
\Fullpages
\NoKey
\NumberOfVersions{1}

\let\namedata\relax

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{numquestions}
\setcounter{numquestions}{0}
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\addtocounter{numquestions}{1}}

\newcounter{mc}
\setcounter{mc}{0}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multiplechoice}{\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\addtocounter{mc}{1}}}
\AtEndEnvironment{multiplechoice}{\setcounter{mc}{\value{mc}}}

\newcounter{sa}
\setcounter{sa}{0}
\AtBeginEnvironment{shortanswer}{\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\addtocounter{sa}{1}}}


\usepackage{totcount}

\newtotcounter{s}
\setcounter{s}{0}
\newenvironment{mcquestion}[1]{
    \stepcounter{s}
    \begin{question} 
    #1 
    \end{question}
   }


\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}
This exam is worth all the marbles. It contains  \themc\ MC questions and \thesa\ short answer questions. There are a total of \thenumquestions\ questions.\\
\end{examtop}

\begin{multiplechoice}[]

\begin{mcquestion}
    Yes?
        \choice[!]{Yes.}
        \choice{No.}
\end{mcquestion}


\begin{question}
  True?
    \choice[!]{True.}
    \choice{False.}
    \choice{Maybe.}
    \choice{Dunno.}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  False?
    \choice{True.}
    \choice[!]{False.}
    \choice{Maybe.}
    \choice{Dunno.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{shortanswer}[]
\begin{question}
What is love?
\begin{answer}
Baby don't hurt me. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
What is the meaning of life?
\begin{answer}
42. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Are you sure?
\begin{answer}
Yes. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SectionFont{\large\bfseries\ttfamily}
\ContinuousNumbering
\Fullpages
\NoKey
\NumberOfVersions{1}

\let\namedata\relax

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{qcount}
\setcounter{qcount}{0}
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\addtocounter{qcount}{1}}

\newcounter{mcount}
\setcounter{mcount}{0}
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\ifbool{insidemc}{\addtocounter{mcount}{1}}{}}

\newbool{insidemc}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{multiplechoice}[1][]
  {\setbool{insidemc}{true}
  \begin{section}
   \def\@currentsectionname{multiplechoice}
   \exam@definesectiontype{multiplechoice}
   \exam@SetDefaultRearrangeBehavior
   \exam@SetDefaultSectionTitle{\exam@notitle}
   \exam@SetDefaultRecountState{\exam@DefaultNumberingBehavior}
   \setkeys{section}{#1}%
   \get@instructions \relax}
  {\end{section}
  \setbool{insidemc}{false}}
\makeatother  

\newcounter{scount}
\setcounter{scount}{0}
\AtBeginEnvironment{question}{\ifbool{insides}{\addtocounter{scount}{1}}{}}

\newbool{insides}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{shortanswer}[1][]
  {\setbool{insides}{true}
  \begin{section}
   \def\@currentsectionname{shortanswer}
   \exam@definesectiontype{shortanswer}
   \exam@SetDefaultRearrangeBehavior
   \exam@SetDefaultSectionTitle{\exam@notitle}
   \exam@SetDefaultRecountState{\exam@DefaultNumberingBehavior}
   \setkeys{section}{#1}%
   \get@instructions \relax}
  {\end{section}
  \setbool{insides}{false}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}
This exam is worth all the marbles. It contains  
\themcount\ 
MC questions and 
\thescount\ 
short answer questions. There are a total of 
\theqcount\ 
questions.\\
\end{examtop}

\begin{multiplechoice}[]

\begin{question}
    Yes?
        \choice[!]{Yes.}
        \choice{No.}
\end{question}


\begin{question}
  True?
    \choice[!]{True.}
    \choice{False.}
    \choice{Maybe.}
    \choice{Dunno.}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  False?
    \choice{True.}
    \choice[!]{False.}
    \choice{Maybe.}
    \choice{Dunno.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}

\begin{shortanswer}[]
\begin{question}
What is love?
\begin{answer}
Baby don't hurt me. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
What is the meaning of life?
\begin{answer}
42. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Are you sure?
\begin{answer}
Yes. 
\end{answer}
\end{question}
\end{shortanswer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Could you explain what is going on?

Comment: @invictus I use a bool to find out if the question is inside a MC or short answer and increment the counter based on this.

Comment: Cool - but why can't I do arithmetic with these counters? For example, if I define a counter called `points`, then I should be able to do something like `\setcounter{points}{1*\value{mcount} + 2*\value{scount}}` (using the `calc` package) and display it with `thepoints`. But this returns zero where it should return 9.

Comment: @invictus You could look into `\numexpr` to do such calculations, but actually its not necessary, just use `\newcounter{points}
\addtocounter{points}{\themcount}
\addtocounter{points}{\thescount}
\addtocounter{points}{\thescount}
\thepoints`